# Pascal: Error al calcular dos maximos

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Estoy teniendo inconvenientes al momento de calcular los dos máximos en Pascal.
El inconveniente me pasa solo en el primer máximo (max1), ya que el segundo máximo (max2) me lo retorna correctamente.

Además, me pedía calcular dos mínimos, los cuales me retornan correctamente.

Para ponerlos en contexto, el programa me pide:

-Código de los dos aviones con mayor cantidad de km: (el que el procedimiento que retorna mal)

Este procedimiento tiene los parámetros por referencia:

- Avion, que es un registro
- max1, max2 están inicializados en el programa principal con -1
  -Cod_AvionMax1 y Cod_AvionMax2 deben ser lo que retorna la función.
  En este caso, me retorna mal Cod_AvionMax1. ¿Por qué debería ser? si yo calcule el max y el mínimo con la misma lógica, y el mínimo es retornado correctamente.

```
procedure AvionesMax_km (var i2: Avion; var max1, max2: real; var Cod_AvionMax1, Cod_AvionMax2: real ); 

begin
    if i2.Km_recorridos > max1 then
    begin
        max2:= max1; 
        max1:= i2.Km_recorridos; 
        Cod_AvionMax2:= Cod_AvionMax1; 
        Cod_AvionMax2:= i2.Cod_Avion ; 
    end
    else
    begin
        if i2.Km_recorridos > max2 then 
        begin
            max2:= i2.Km_recorridos; 
            Cod_AvionMax2:= i2.Cod_Avion ; 
        end;        
    end; 
end;
```

-Código de los dos aviones con menor cantidad de km (este módulo retorna correctamente)

```
procedure AvionesMin_km (var i3: Avion;var min1, min2: real; var Cod_AvionMin1, Cod_AvionMin2: real); 
begin
    if i3.Km_recorridos < min1 then 
    begin
        min2:= min1 ; 
        min1:= i3.Km_recorridos; 
        Cod_AvionMin2:= Cod_AvionMin1 ;
        Cod_AvionMin1:= i3.Cod_Avion; 
    end 
    else
    begin
        if i3.Km_recorridos < min2 then         
        begin
            min2:= i3.Km_recorridos; 
            Cod_AvionMin2:= i3.Cod_Avion ; 
        end;            
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Yo editaría la pregunta para explicar qué significan los parámetros de la función: AvionesMax_km 

Qué significan los parámetros y qué valores debe retornar en cadsa caso.

Comment: perfecto, gracias ahi lo hago

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la función no tiene mucho sentido en su definición y eso hace que no estemos (o al menos yo) entendiendo bien lo que intentas hacer. Por lo tanto, es difícil saber qué está mal. me explico...

Intentar abstraerte de tu programa e intenta pensar (así lo hago yo) algo con lógica.

Si a mi me piden una función que calcule **"Código de los dos aviones con mayor cantidad de km"** (palabras exactas de tu texto), yo sin saber nada más, diseñaría una función así:

```
procedure AvionesMax_km(aListaAviones:TList<avion>; var av1,av2:avion);

procedure AvionesMax_km(aListaAviones:TList<avion>; var Cod_Av1,Cod_av2:real);
```

No entiendo cómo si sólo pasas la información de **1 avión** y **2 máximos** (que pueden ser los máximos hasta ahora calculados anteriomente imagino) vas a retornar el código de 2 aviones. No tiene sentido.

Tampoco veo que si inicializas los **maximos a -1** (como comentas) puedas calcular ningun valor.

**CONSEJO1:**
Independientemente de que te funcione o no, creo que deberías "rediseñar" la función con algo que tenga más lógica.

**CONSEJO2:**
Si ya tienes información en el o`bjeto/record` `avion`, utiliza esos objetos en las funciones. Es decir, en lugar de trabajar con `max1` (que es el máximo de 1 `avión`) pasa directamente la variable `avión` (con el máximo de km), y cuando lo necesites utiliza, `avion.Km_recorridos`.